# Access array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How can I access array of objects ( and properties ) in Javascript?
I have an array of Users (object properties : userID , fName , lName ) in my action and want to show lName of users in auto complete tags. 
I write this code in jsp:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
    <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
<s:hidden id="s" value="%{Users}"/>
```

and in this JSP write java script code:

```
    <script> 
    $(function() {          
        var values = document.getElementById('s').value;
        var availableTags = values.split(",");

        function split( val ) {
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }

    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

but this code show class name in auto complete,Like this: Classes.User@ee662

Comment: what is the specific relevant code ?

Comment: i want to access user lname, but can not!

Comment: Your value in this case is a simple `string`, instead of doing a string `split` you could just turn that string (assuming it's a proper JSON) into a Javascript object by using `myObject = JSON.parse(values);`

Comment: tanks.but i should other changes in above code?